# Two Keyspace on Same DC

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I already created one keyspace on DC.

Create query for tradebees_dev keyspace :-  (This keyspace is working fine.)

```
CREATE KEYSPACE tradebees_dev WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'solr': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

Status is below :-

```
nodetool status tradebees_dev

Datacenter: Solr
================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  1.09 GB    256     100.0%            e754d239-8370-4e1d-82c8-dce3d401f972  rack1
UN  127.0.0.2  1.19 GB    256     100.0%            70b74025-1881-4756-a0c8-a1ec5e57d407  rack1
UN  127.0.0.3  1.53 GB    256     100.0%            3ba4bfe4-c894-4cd1-a684-f0f20edac78f  rack1
```

After that I created another keyspace on same DC with same replication factor .

Create query for crawl_dev keyspace :-

```
CREATE KEYSPACE crawl_dev WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'solr': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;

nodetool status crawl_dev

Datacenter: Solr
================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  1.09 GB    256     0.0%              e754d239-8370-4e1d-82c8-dce3d401f972  rack1
UN  127.0.0.2  1.19 GB    256     0.0%              70b74025-1881-4756-a0c8-a1ec5e57d407  rack1
UN  127.0.0.3  1.53 GB    256     0.0%              3ba4bfe4-c894-4cd1-a684-f0f20edac78f  rack1
```

As first keyspace is working fine but when I am trying to do select query on second keyspace i.e on crawl_dev , I am getting below error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/dse/resources/cassandra/bin/cqlsh", line 1124, in perform_simple_statement
    rows = self.session.execute(statement, trace=self.tracing_enabled)
  File "/usr/share/dse/resources/cassandra/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-2.7.2-5d33cb4.zip/cassandra-driver-2.7.2-5d33cb4/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1602, in execute
    result = future.result()
  File "/usr/share/dse/resources/cassandra/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-2.7.2-5d33cb4.zip/cassandra-driver-2.7.2-5d33cb4/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3347, in result
    raise self._final_exception
Unavailable: code=1000 [Unavailable exception] message="Cannot achieve consistency level ONE" info={'required_replicas': 1, 'alive_replicas': 0, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

Please suggest me how to resolve this issue. and also let me know can we create two keyspaces on same DC . YES or NO.

After some research , I got info then I checked

```
/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra-rackdc.properties
```

in this file , dc=DC1 and rc=RACK1 is given. 
Thanks.

Comment: Does it happens on all tables of keyspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datacenter name in the "create keyspace" command is case-sensitive, so instead of:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE tradebees_dev WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'solr': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

you want to capitalize Solr, for example:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE tradebees_dev WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'Solr': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

You're on the right track for troubleshooting with your "nodetool status [keyspace]" commands. Notice in your result for tradebees_dev, each node reports 100% in the Owns column, which makes sense because you have RF 3 on a 3-node cluster. Then notice for crawl_dev it shows 0% which means *no* nodes own that data, and hence the error you received. In your example above I suspect you did create tradebees_dev with capital "Solr" in the replication factory and that's why it worked.

Comment: yes I altered the keyspace DC's name and that is working fine.CREATE KEYSPACE crawl_dev WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'Solr': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;
 and it  is now working fine for me.

Comment: Great! Would you mind "accepting" this answer so others who come later will know this was the solution?

Comment: Sure.. But what do you mean by accepting this answer..Can you tell me in more details. And is it possible that I can get your any contact details like mail id, whatsapp or wechat or skype where I can talk with you directly.. Will be great for me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NandanPriyadarshi here's the info on how to accept an answer on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. And if you have more questions just tag them with datastax-enterprise and folks in the community will continue to help.

Comment: I accepted your answer.. Can I get your contact details like email id or some thing else.. where I can contact you frequently.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you should not be able to create multiple keyspaces on the same DC. Indeed, you already have multiple keyspaces in the cluster:

```
cqlsh> DESCRIBE keyspaces;

system_traces  system_schema  system_auth  system  system_distributed
```